# How to export original unique values using awk

Tags: bash, awk

This command works great for concatenating duplicates and giving only unique values:

`awk '!x[$0]++' filewithdupes > newfile`

However, I want to *keep* the *original* unique values.

Example:

If I have this simple set of values in a CSV column:

```
1
1
2
2
3
```

The command above outputs this:

```
1
2
3
```

But I want:

```
3
```

How can I modify this command to *keep* the original unique value? Or is there a command better suited to what I'm trying to do?

Comment: `uniq -u file.csv`

Comment: @Cyrus, ...though that does require that the content already be sorted (which is true in the OP's example, but not clear if that's true through the full domain of content it needs to be able to handle).

Answer (score 1):

You may use this `awk` to print record that has only one occurrence:

```
awk '{x[$0]++} END{for (i in x) if (x[i] == 1) print i}' filewithdupes
```

```
3
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0]++;next} a[$0]==1'  Input_file Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

if your file is already sorted as in the example, the simplest will be

```
$ uniq -u file

3
```

otherwise, a double scan algorithm

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++; next} a[$1]==1' file{,}

3
```